# DotNetNuke: debugging module when running dnn under iis express?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Does anybody know how to set this up? I have under module's project properties start url as http://localhost:16555/default.aspx which is what webmatrix shows as my dnn site.
I tried using locall IIS express web server, tried custom but it always shows that symbols were not loaded, and it showing them as being loaded from temp asp.net folder, not from the dnn bin.

Comment: Is your module compiled or dynamic?  (WAP or WSP structure)

Comment: I never had success using the built-in VStudio web server. I always take the time to setup an IIS site, and set IIS as the web server in each module's project settings.